# found a bound for a recursive sequence

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

If $C\geq 0$ , show that sequence:
\begin{eqnarray}
 a_{1}=C, \hspace{0.5cm} a_{n}= C\sqrt{1+a_{n-1}} 
\end{eqnarray}
for each $n\geq 2$. Is monotone, bounded and compute $\lim a_{n}$

---

I show that is increase monotone but I have problems with the bound, I propose $(C+1)^{2}$ like a bound, Is this a good choose? or can you give me some suggest of a bound? and If I suppose that sequence is increase monotone and upper bounded it's easy compute the limit. Thank you

Comment: Since you know that the sequence is increasing monotonously and is bounded, you can find the limit/bound by setting $a_n = a_{n-1}$, which may help proving boundedness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$a_0=C \leq 2C \leq  1+C^{2}$ and if $a_{n-1}\leq 1+C^{2}$ then $a_n \leq C\sqrt {2+C^{2}} \leq 1+C^{2}$. So $a_n \leq 1+C^{2}$ for all $n$.